# Image not displaying on MVVM XAML Xamarin Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have tried unsuccessfully for 2 days to display image on my Xaml from MVVM Xamarin forms.  I would appreciate if someone could help me with this issue.
Here is my code:

**XAML**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition Height="*" />
         <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <Image Source="{Binding GetImageSource}"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
       <Image Source="camera.png" HorizontalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
       <Image.GestureRecognizers>
           <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding TakePhoto}" />
       </Image.GestureRecognizers>
     </Image>
</Grid>
```

**My ViewModel**

**Using Plugin.Media (Choose image from gallery)**

I've used TapGestureRecognizer

Which is working fine

```
private ImageSource imageSource { get; set; }

public ImageSource GetImageSource
{
    get { return imageSource; }
    set
    {
        imageSource = value;
    }
}

if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsPickPhotoSupported)
{
    var message = "Picking image is not supported";
    DependencyService.Get<IMessage>().ShortAlert(message);
    return;
}
var files = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync();
if (files == null)
    return;

GetImageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
{
    var stream = files.GetStream();

    return stream;
});
var ms = new MemoryStream();
files.GetStream().CopyTo(ms);
files.Dispose();
imgAsBytes = ms.ToArray();
ms.Dispose();
```

I have managed to get the image in byte which is fine, but I can't display the image.
Thanks in advance for your support.

Comment: does your VM implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged) for your ViewModel class and invoke `PropertyChanged` to your property setter. Like,

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
public ImageSource GetImageSource
{
    get { return imageSource; }
    set
    {
        imageSource = value;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(GetImageSource)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi dhilmathy, I tried your solution, but it didn't work out.

Comment: @prezequias `DataContext` set fine for your `View`? Whether other property binding works?

Comment: yes, binding is working fine, actually, I am using prism Xamarin Forms

Answer (score 0):

Here is my Xamarin MVVM solution.  First the XAML for the image and button to select it:

```
  <Image x:Name="WaypointImage" Source="{Binding MyImage}" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
  <Button Text="Gallery" FontSize="Large" Command="{Binding SelectPhoto}"    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BorderWidth="2" CornerRadius="20" Margin="2, 10, 2, 20"/>
```

This is bound to this data structure in the C# ViewModel code:

```
   private ImageSource _myImage;
   public ImageSource MyImage
   {
      get => _myImage;
      set
      {
         _myImage = value;
         RaisePropertyChanged(() => MyImage);
         // take any additional actions here which are required when MyImage is updated
      }
   }
```

Finally, the code in the same file to select the image from the gallery, copy it to the local app cache, and set MyImage to display it:

```
   public MvxCommand SelectPhoto => new MvxCommand(SelectPhotoAsync);
   public async void SelectPhotoAsync()
   {
      try
      {
         var photo = await MediaPicker.PickPhotoAsync();
         await LoadPhotoAsync(photo);
         Console.WriteLine($"CapturePhotoAsync COMPLETED: {MyFilename}");
      }
      catch (FeatureNotSupportedException fnsEx)
      {
         // Feature is not supported on the device
      }
      catch (PermissionException pEx)
      {
         // Permissions not granted
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
         Console.WriteLine($"PickPhotoAsync THREW: {ex.Message}");
      }
   }

   async Task LoadPhotoAsync(FileResult photo)
   {
      // canceled
      if (photo == null)
      {
         MyFilename = null;
         return;
      }
      // save the file into local storage
      var newFile = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, photo.FileName);
      using (var stream = await photo.OpenReadAsync())
         using (var newStream = File.OpenWrite(newFile))
         await stream.CopyToAsync(newStream);
      
      MyFilename = newFile;
      // bug currently prevents storing image in DB
      // byte[] readBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(MyFilename);
      // waypoint.Image = readBytes.ToArray();
      // Just store filename and use local storage for image instead of DB
      waypoint.FileName = newFile;
      StoreWaypoint();
      MyImage = ImageSource.FromFile(newFile);
   }
}
```